# Magento 1.9: Add custom text box on invoice page for partial capture

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway, custom-field, partial-payments, partial-invoice

I have created a payment module with auth-capture option and its working properly in Magento 1.9. The requirement is to capture a portion of the amount without changing the quantity. For this I have added a custom button "Partial Capture" on invoice page. Now how can I add a custom field on invoice page to enter a partial amount? How can I validate this custom field while clicking on "Partial Capture" button? Now "Partial Capture" button is showing on all invoices. How to show this button only on invoices with status "pending"? Any help will be appreciated.

**Function in observer:**

```
public function addButtons(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View) {
        $message = Mage::helper('core')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?');
        $block->addButton('custom_button', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Partial Capture'),
            'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('onlinepayment/noply/partialcapture')}')",
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
}
```

**Event in config.xml:**

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <custombuttons>
                    <class>onlinepayment/observer</class>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <method>addButtons</method>
                </custombuttons>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Any suggestions?